# PhpStorm high CPU usage on switching windows

Tags: phpstorm, cpu-usage, jetbrains-ide

I am having a lot of issues with PhpStorm when moving quickly between windows (either PhpStorm windows or other widows like Chrome or other applications), it starts to use the CPU very aggressively and would make my fans loud.

This happens so much often even when quickly swapping with <kbd>Command + Tab</kbd>.

My question is what is it using the CPU for ? when I literally swapped away and back to PhpStorm within a single second. This behavior is also very repeatable.

I am opening multiple PhpStorm windows but I only use a couple of them most of the time, although this issue is also present when using one or two windows only.

Comment: Generally speaking: 1) When switching from PhpStorm to another app the IDE can save currently unsaved files. Perhaps you have some scripts that watch for file changes (like `npm watch` or alike). Standard File Watcher can do the same (run certain app when file gets saved). 2) When switching from another app to PhpStorm: the IDE at this point would normally check your project files looking for external changes. If it sees such changes it can be re-indexing those files... Check for those things / what you may have there in your setup.